# JRuby: changed CLASSPATH but no effect

Tags: java, windows, classpath, jruby

```
include Java

cp = ENV["CLASSPATH"]
cp.split(/[;]/).each{|el| puts "#{el}"}
```

I changed a path in my `CLASSPATH` environment variable via regedit in Windows 7 but when I run the script above it prints me the old paths. Why doesn't it recognize that `CLASSPATH` has changed?

**edit:** It works after a computer reboot, but can't it work without having to do that?

Answer (score 1):

just `set CLASSPATH=` before running the script (will be kept until you close that particular command line) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

alternatively explicitly specify `-cp` on the command line with `jruby` :

`jruby -J-classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\foo.jar ...` (overrides `CLASSPATH`)